# Ionic/angular child pages with nested ion-router-outlet

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, scroll

I have some static content that displays on the top of my nested routes. The child pages are being displayed in a nested ion-router-outlet that displays on the page. The problem is because of all the position absolute and layouts I end up having multiple scroll areas.

What is the best approach to get make the nested ion-router-outlet NOT generate scroll ares and rather just give itself a set height which can then make the parent handle all the scrolling.